# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Tags: jquery

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined.
code-

```
if (document.getElementById('pic')[0].size > 102400) {
        alert("Pic size exceeds");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[getDocumentById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a dom element reference not an array/collection of objects so there is no index `0`

```
if (document.getElementById('pic').size > 102400) {
    alert("Pic size exceeds");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple in jquery

```
if ($('#pic').size > 102400) {
        alert("Pic size exceeds");
 }
```